# Javascript why doesn't IE execute this code?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, closures

I all, i am making a web site ( http://euroscala.balkanium.com/ ) which has a menu, and when you click on a menu item, a thumbnail list should appear. I am trying to preload all the images that should appear and then display them. It works fine on every browser except IE (i have version 8). I have put together the code for anyone willing to take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/THpgM/2/

I think the problem lies in this piece of code (which is near the bottom of the first function in the fiddle)

```
img.onload = (function(i){ 
  // code here is executed

  return function(){
    // code here is not

    ++totalLoaded;
    document.getElementById("li" + i).style.height = this.height + "px";
    document.getElementById("li" + i).setAttribute("data-height", this.height);

    if(totalLoaded == totalThumbs){
      // do some stuff
    }
  };
})(i);
```

I have spent like 2 days trying to figure this out. If someone could please help me with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try using subscript notation with "data-height" ...  for example `someElement["data-height"] = 1` or `var height = someElement["data-height"]` instead of getAttribute/setAttribute.

Comment: @MarkLinus as i write in the comments, the code after `return ...` doesnot execute

Comment: @GGG i will try that now and let u know

Comment: @GGG i tried this
`var myLi = document.getElementById("li" + i);
myLi.style.height = this.height + "px";
myLi.["data-height"] = this.height;`

..but it's not working. Im not sure if i am doing it right though.

Comment: @LeandroZhuzhi `myLi["data-height"] = this.height;`, and then you'd want to get it the same way. I would probably post this code on codereview.stackexchange.com, someone could have a field day with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In IE you MUST assign the `.onload` handler BEFORE you assign `.src`.  If you don't, then the onload event might fire before your onload handler is in place and you will miss the event.

```
// assign .onload before .src
img.onload = function() {};
img.src = "xxx.jpg";
```

The particular issue in IE will happen if the images are in the browser cache (thus they load immediately when `.src` is assigned) and your onload handler will never execute.

So, in your jsFiddle, move the assignment to `.src` to be after the assignment to `.onload`.